# Interpolating instance values in hibernate validator messages?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

Is it possible to get values from the instance being validated and interpolating those values into the validation message?

For example suppose I'm validating an item with a price and a cost.  I wish create a message like this:

`The price of $10 must be greater than cost of $20.`

How do I get the price and the cost from the instance?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 0):

try this:

messages.properties

```
non.unique.ssn=SSN {0} already exist. Please fill in different value
```

in Controller:

```
if(!service.isEmployeeSsnUnique(employee.getId(), employee.getSsn())){
            FieldError ssnError =new FieldError("employee","ssn",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssn", new String[]{employee.getSsn()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(ssnError);
            return "registration";
        }
```

**Update 1**

```
Size.employee.name=Name must be between {2} and {1} characters long
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;
//..
}
```

will display this message:

> Name must be between 50 and 3 characters long

**Update 2**

To create a custom constraint, the following three steps are required:

> Create a constraint annotation
>
> Implement a validator
>
> Define a default error message

For example: [Creating custom constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints)

Comment: In this case I have built a custom validator that works at the Type / Class level, so I need to be able to access two fields on the instance being validated and interpolate the values of those fields into the message.

Comment: It looks like you are pulling the min and max parameters from the annotation for a single field.  I my case I need to access two fields (Price and Cost) and I want to interpolate those values into the message.  I can do it post validation, but it would be nice to be able to do it during.

Comment: Can you display message for each field and then concatenate them ?

Comment: The validation is based on both fields.  If cost is greater than price, then it is triggered.

Comment: Ok.. i think creating a custom constraint will resolve your issue.. im not on my laptop now.. will share with you later.. how to create your own constraint

Comment: So in this case how would I get for example the parameters passed to the constructor new Car( "VW", "USD-123", 4 ) interpolated into the message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116122/discussion-between-ole-and-fussa).